# How to get the value of `submit.preloader_id = "div#some-id";` in `beforesend` method inside ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code written in javascript,

```
var submit = {
  preloader_id: "",

  send:function (form_id) {
    var url = $(form_id).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(form_id).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success:(result) => {
      },
      error: function(result) {
        // Some errors
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        console.log(this.preloader_id);
        if (this.preloader_id != "") {
          run_preloader(this.preloader_id);
        }
      },
      completes: function() {
        if (this.preloader_id != "") {
          run_preloader(this.preloader_id, 'true');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and is called like this

```
submit.preloader_id = "form-id";
submit.send('div#some-id');
```

The problem is when I tried to get value assigned in `preloader_id` inside this method

```
beforeSend: function() {
  console.log(this.preloader_id); // look if there is id name to fetch
  if (this.preloader_id != "") {
    run_preloader(this.preloader_id);
  }
},
```

I get undefined,

How to get the value of `submit.preloader_id = "div#some-id";` in `beforesend` method inside ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the scope of `this` has changed within the `beforeSend` handler of `$.ajax`. To fix this, store the reference outside the handler:

```
var submit = {
  preloader_id: "",

  send:function (form_id) {
    var _this = this; // store here
    var url = $(form_id).attr("action");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(form_id).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success:(result) => {},
      error: function(result) {
        // Some errors
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        // use here...
        console.log(_this.preloader_id);
        if (_this.preloader_id != "") {
          run_preloader(_this.preloader_id);
        }
      },
      completes: function() {
        // and here...
        if (_this.preloader_id != "") {
          run_preloader(_this.preloader_id, 'true');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the wrong context. Add `var that = this` inside your `send` method and refer to preloader_id via it: `that.preloader_id`